# Interested in trekking to Annapurna Base Camp

Tags: trekking

I got injured at the age of 16 and damaged my right knee ligament. I had a surgery. After gaining strength, I started playing again and that damaged the reconstruction. And now, at the age of 34, with regular exercise, I have got some strength again. Now I can run and jump to catch a moving bus and even a train.

Can I trek to Annapurna Base Camp at 4130 meter by walking 6 hrs daily for 10 days?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not something the internet can answer for you. That is an entirely personal question and should be answered by testing (gradually start walking) and/or your doctor.

Comment: It's nothing personal Joyjeet, but I agree with imsodin and for the same reasons am voting to close. That surgery you had is difficult. I'm so glad you're feeling better and interested in a difficult trek. I also hope you keep asking and answering questions here!

Comment: I am OK with closing the topic. I have already got my answers and / or suggestions in this wonderful platform. Due to lack of self confidence but plenty of desire, I was unable make a concrete decision. So I posted this question. Thank you all for your guidance.

Comment: Voting to re-open there are good answers that are in scope that will add value for other readers.

Comment: @Joyjeet: The vague nature of this basic question has been the reason to close it off. Please do not be discouraged with this. I personally believe that such a question can not be answered straight away. The reason being, there are various parameters to consider before you plan any such trek. Have you been trekking? Because, 4130 m is still some serious altitude for a guy living at the sea shores, believe me I am from Mumbai. While I appreciate your interests to come over historical injuries and climb a mountain, I'd suggest to take the right steps: Develop a regular hiking habit.

Comment: @Joyjeet: (Continued..) This is all with assumption that you have not been trekking. Regular hiking/trekking would help in getting familiar with basic skills that you need acquire to spend days outdoors and still enjoy your time rather than feeling physically stressed. If I were you, I would have started off with 1 day, 2-3 days of treks/hikes around my place to know if I really want to keep doing this, because, trekking and mountaineering activities require a set of skills which is way different and broader than catching a running bus or a train. Stay safe!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short run is not even close to 6 hours with a pack.

If you are not mobile and have to be extracted it could get expensive.

Take some back to back long days with a full pack and see how you feel.

Comment: You don't have to carry a pack for the Annapurna.

Comment: I'll start working on it soon and test myself. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ppl Really hike 6 hours without a pack?

Comment: @ppl Then that would be your full pack.

Answer (score 9):

With that given information we can't tell if **you** can do it. I, for example had an knee surgery too while playing soccer some years ago. Still I am driving to work by bike regularly and I am doing other sports. And I am hiking and climbing. So yes, for myself I can decide and I would be pretty sure I could do it.

But how should we say that for you? Are you doing any sport? If you are just running 1 minute to catch a train say once a week, then I wouldn't suggest to fly to Nepal just to notice a day later that you don't have the endurance. Walking 10 days each day 6 hours isn't easy. So please, do yourself a favour and start in your local hills or even in the city to run slowly for a decent amount of time. You even don't have to run, you can start by hiking two hours on Sundays for example. Then you do it on two days. Then you increase the length of the hike...

You get the point. Maybe you notice after 2 weeks that it's very easy for you and you have good stamina. Maybe you don't. Just try it out by yourself, the internet can't give you an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. I will definitely follow these suggestions.

Comment: This doesn't consider/address the specific trek.

Comment: @ppl What should be considered here? That you don't have to carry a  backpack because of Sherpas is right. But that doesn't change the fact, that you have to train to be able to walk 6 hr daily for 10 days (as OP says). And you have to get **any** idea how fit you are, therefore my recommendation to try it out. Otherwise we can't really help tbh.

Comment: Terrain, trekking services available, incorporation of zero days for altitude acclimation, evacuation options, food supply, alternative mode transportation available, remoteness (or lack of). All of those makes this trek favorable for the given scenario.

Comment: @ppl Still he has to know where he stands and this info can't be given here from strangers. The fitness/endurance level is the main question and the main advice we can give OP is to get an idea how he performs. We can't post a full abstract on this particular trek just because OP wants to try it.

Comment: I think that aspect of the question belongs in a separate question and I imagine we already have one such question/answer. To me, the value of the question/answer would be that given a personal injury, when I read the answer, can I access if this trek is a viable option. For that, I need trek information. Imoh, the question "how to access my fitness for a trek" should be the preamble of the question; a single line/paragraph. The core of it should address the trek. Anyway, this is now closed. :)